# Need to compare two arrays with a callback and return an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Construct a function `objOfMatches` that accepts two arrays and a callback. `objOfMatches` will build an object and return it. To build the object, `objOfMatches` will test each element of the first array using the callback to see if the output matches the corresponding element (by index) of the second array. If there is a match, the element from the first array becomes a key in an object, and the element from the second array becomes the corresponding value. I got this so far:

```
const objOfMatches = (arr1,arr2,call) => {
let result = {};
for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
 //Don't know how to check each element using the callback
}
return result
}


const arr1 = ['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'];
const arr2 = ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'later', 'HELLO'];
function uppercaser(str) { return str.toUpperCase(); }
console.log(objOfMatches(arr1, arr2, uppercaser)); 
// should log: { hi: 'HI', bye: 'BYE', hello: 'HELLO' }
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
const objOfMatches = (arr1,arr2,call) => {
     let result = {};
     for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
          let upper = call(arr1[i]);
          if(arr2[i] && upper == arr2[i])
               result[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];
     }
     return result
}
const arr1 = ['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'];
const arr2 = ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'later', 'HELLO'];
function uppercaser(str) { return str.toUpperCase(); }
console.log(objOfMatches(arr1, arr2, uppercaser));
```

Comment: Why do I need to set a variable to use the callback? Why can't I use it inside the If statement?

Comment: you can: ``if(arr2[i] && call(arr1[i]) == arr2[i])``

Answer (score 2):

Here is a functional programming solution:

```js
const objOfMatches = (arr1, arr2, call) => 
    Object.fromEntries(arr1.map((v,i) => [v, arr2[i]])
                           .filter(([a,b]) => call(a) === b));


const arr1 = ['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'];
const arr2 = ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'later', 'HELLO'];
const uppercaser = str => str.toUpperCase();
console.log(objOfMatches(arr1, arr2, uppercaser));
```

### Explanation

`objOfMatches` is a function defined with arrow syntax, where the part that follows the (first) `=>` is the expression that determines the function's return value. The same arrow syntax is used for all other functions in this solution as well.

First the two arrays are "zipped" into one array of pairs, using `arr1.map((v,i) => [v, arr2[i]])`. This takes every value `v` from `arr1` and pairs it with the value from `arr2` that sits at the same index. So for the example input, this produces the following:

```
[
  ['hi', 'HI'],
  ['howdy', 'Howdy'],
  ['bye', 'BYE'],
  ['later', 'later'],
  ['hello', 'HELLO']
]
```

Then `.filter` is called on this intermediate result, only keeping the pairs `[a,b]` where `call(a) === b`. So then we have:

```
[
  ['hi', 'HI'],
  ['bye', 'BYE'],
  ['hello', 'HELLO']
]
```

Finally, this is passed as argument to the `Object.fromEntries` function, which turns an array of key/value pairs into a plain object having those keys and values.

Comment: This is a very concise and elegant solution. Would you mind walking through it with a bit of an explanation?

Comment: I have added a section with an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const objOfMatches = (arr1,arr2,call) => {
  let result = {};
  arr1.forEach((item, i) => {
     if(call(item) === arr2[i]) {
      result[item] = arr2[i]
     }
  })
  return result;
}


const arr1 = ['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'];
const arr2 = ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'later', 'HELLO'];
function uppercaser(str) { return str.toUpperCase(); }
console.log(objOfMatches(arr1, arr2, uppercaser)); 
// should log: { hi: 'HI', bye: 'BYE', hello: 'HELLO' }
```

Comment: Seems the same solution as Majed's, who posted it 6 minutes before you.

Comment: @trincot now it's a little different

Answer (score 0):

```
const objOfMatches = (array1, array2, callback) => array1.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (callback(curr) === prev.compareAgainst[0]) {
    prev.obj[curr] = prev.compareAgainst[0];
  }
  prev.compareAgainst = prev.compareAgainst.slice(1);
  return prev;
}, {obj: {}, compareAgainst: array2}).obj;

console.log(objOfMatches(['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'], ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'LATER', 'hello'], (str) => str.toUpperCase()));
// should log: { hi: 'HI', bye: 'BYE', later: 'LATER' }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).